# Can't Read data From Access Database After Publishing On IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I have An ASP.Net web site which reads data from an Access database, It works well, but after publishing it on IIS no data is retrieved.

I'm using the Web config to connect to database

```
<add name="GisDB" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\AccessDB\Myacdb.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
```

Comment: Were going to need far more information. Where is the MDB placed in the folder structure ? Did you copy it to the equivalent folder in IIS ? How does your website know where the file is ? Do you use standard Web.config connection strings etc.etc.

Comment: I'm Using The Web config to connect to database                              <add name="GisDB" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\AccessDB\Myacdb.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"  providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>

Answer (score 0):

You may have two specific issues to resolve:
1) IIS cant resolve the path of the Access Database
2) IIS may not be able to instantiate the ACE OLEDB drivers on the server.

A potential solution for 1) is to place the Access database in your /App_Data subfolder off the root of your website. You can specify a connectionstring in the web.config like this

Resolving 2) is trickier, especially if its a remote host. As a start, If using Visual Studio, compile your website binary into x86 mode and see if the problem persists. This could indicate a potential issue with the Access DLLs running on a 64 bit platform.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly IIS worker process does not have rights to read files in the d:\AccessDB\ folder. Either grant it rights or move the MDB to an App_Data folder under your website root and change the Web.Config to suit.